# NServiceBus.ExceptionInfo.Message An error occurred while attempting to extract logical messages from transport message NServiceBus.TransportMessage

Tags: nservicebus

I am receiving de-serialization messages on handling events from particular.ServiceControl.

**Headers:**

```
NServiceBus.MessageId 666faf48-0c44-4109-beb6-a66a009c8c93
NServiceBus.CorrelationId bf397ea0-6a`enter code here`aa-4c7f-ba2c-a66a009c8c93
NServiceBus.MessageIntent Publish
NServiceBus.Version 5.2.10
NServiceBus.TimeSent 2016-08-22 16:29:58:673549 Z
NServiceBus.ContentType application/json
NServiceBus.EnclosedMessageTypes ServiceControl.Contracts.MessageFailed, ServiceControl.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
CorrId 666faf48-0c44-4109-beb6-a66a009c8c93\0
NServiceBus.ConversationId 68a1e495-d47a-4eef-8a96-a66a009c8c93
WinIdName NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
NServiceBus.OriginatingMachine MS10582
NServiceBus.OriginatingEndpoint Particular.ServiceControl
NServiceBus.ReplyToAddress Particular.ServiceControl@MS10582
NServiceBus.ExceptionInfo.ExceptionType System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
NServiceBus.ExceptionInfo.InnerExceptionType System.Exception
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
at NServiceBus.DeserializeLogicalMessagesBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Messages\DeserializeLogicalMessagesBehavior.cs:line 49
at NServiceBus.CallbackInvocationBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\CallbackInvocationBehavior.cs:line 23
at NServiceBus.ApplyIncomingTransportMessageMutatorsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\MessageMutator\ApplyIncomingTransportMessageMutatorsBehavior.cs:line 20
at NServiceBus.SubscriptionReceiverBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Subscriptions\MessageDrivenSubscriptions\SubscriptionReceiverBehavior.cs:line 32
at NServiceBus.UnitOfWorkBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\UnitOfWork\UnitOfWorkBehavior.cs:line 43
at NServiceBus.ChildContainerBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Unicast\Behaviors\ChildContainerBehavior.cs:line 17
at NServiceBus.ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Monitoring\ProcessingStatisticsBehavior.cs:line 23
at NServiceBus.AuditBehavior.Invoke(IncomingContext context, Action next) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Audit\AuditBehavior.cs:line 20
at NServiceBus.Pipeline.PipelineExecutor.ExecuteT in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Pipeline\PipelineExecutor.cs:line 127
at NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport.TransportReceiver.ProcessMessage(TransportMessage message) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\
```

I can see the messages bodies being received in Servicecontrol but when I try to handle these messages, I am receiving the de-serialization exception.

Comment: What version of SC are you using? Can you share the exception message, endpoint configuration and handler code?

Answer (score 0):

We published a new sample to show how to monitor NServiceBus using ServiceControl events, let me know if that helps http://docs.particular.net/samples/servicecontrol/events-subscription/.